# Ambient Isotopy of Two Arcs in $\mathbb{R}^2$ with Common Endpoints in Rolfsen

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, geometric-topology, knot-theory

Rolfsen's Knots and Links page 10 Exercise 6 states: Let $A$ and $B$ be arcs in $\mathbb{R}^2$ with common endpoints and disjoint interiors. Show that there is an ambient isotopy of $\mathbb{R}^2$, fixed on the endpoints, taking $A$ to $B$. Moreover, the isotopy may be taken to be fixed on any neighbourhood of the closure of the region bounded by $A\cup B$. What if the interiors of $A$ and $B$ intersect?

My problem is that I have no idea how to construct such an ambient isotopy. We can call the two arcs $\gamma$ and $\eta$. I know that the arcs are homotopic by homotopy $F_t(s) = t\gamma (s) + (1-t)\eta (s)$, but extending this homotopy to an ambient isotopy is...unclear at best for me.

I think the idea Rolfson is trying to convey is that I can kinda drag one arc smoothly along the interior of the union of the two arcs, but that would then violate the second part of his statement saying that we can construct an ambient isotopy which even fixes any neighbourhood of the interior of the union of the two arcs.

Is there a better place where I should be looking to get an idea about ambient isotopies and such? It seems like Rolfson is assuming knowledge about these things, but I encountered them in neither Hatcher nor Munkres (for Alg. Top. and Gen. Top., respectively).

Comment: Do you know the Schönflies Theorem?

Comment: Yep! It is given on the page before the exercise. However, part of my issue is more the second statement in the exercise. One of my profs agrees that it is likely a typo...

Comment: The second statement should be "...the isotopy may be taken to be fixed on THE COMPLEMENT OF any neighbourhood of the closure of the region bounded by $A\cup B$."

Comment: Thanks. That's what my prof and I were thinking. Glad I'm not crazy haha. It's weird as a first year student (or as anyone reading a math book haha). Typos become black holes ;P

Comment: To extend this homotopy it must be from $S^1$ to $S^1$, I cannot find a way to define such homotopy which is homeomorphism for each $t$.